# How to correctly apply a 'multiply' tint to an image in HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm using the `multiply` value for the `globalCompositeOperation` property to apply a tint to a clipped region of an image. It works, but the bottom edge of the image sometimes gets a white border.

```js
// Code goes here

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {

    render();

  }

  img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/qiJkgK9.jpg';

  function render() {

    canvas.width = img.width * 2;
    canvas.height = img.height * 2;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.rect(200, 200, 200, 200);
    ctx.clip();

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'multiply';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.restore();

    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.rect(300, 100, 200, 200);
    ctx.clip();

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'multiply';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.restore();

  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

How to prevent the border from appearing OR is there a better way to apply `multiply` tint to an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `fillRect` to the exact rectangle you're looking for instead of `clip` and `fill`, which is causing your clipping issue.

```js
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  function render() {
    canvas.width = img.width * 2;
    canvas.height = img.height * 2;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'multiply';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(200, 200, 200, 200);
    ctx.fillRect(300, 100, 200, 200);
  }

  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = render;
  img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/qiJkgK9.jpg';
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yeah I had tried that initially, but it caused the whole image to change. Different image than I used for the example. Internal, proprietary kind of thing. It sort of shifted the image color palette. Not sure why.

I guess the clip behavior is a Chrome bug.

Comment: @JC. Doesn't matter what the image is behind it, you can see in my answers' code that it works as expected (click on "Run Code Snippet" in a desktop browser). As I mention, you want `fillRect` (as opposed to just `fill`).